# MySQL tables for abstract/concrete classes using Hibernate for ORM

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, abstract

I have the following classes:

```
public abstract class Generic(){
    private int Id;
    ...
}

public class ExtA extends Generic(){
    private Generic fieldA();
    private Generic fieldB();
    ...
}

public class ExtB extends Generic(){
    private Generic fieldA;
    ....
}

public class ExtC extends Generic(){
    ...
}
```

Sorry for the vague example.

I am trying to find a way to save those objects to the database, but can't seem to find a good way. I wish to have separate tables for `ExtA`, `ExtB`, `ExtC`, and then use foreign keys to relate the contained fields. I am using MySQL, and working with Java, Spring, Hibernate. Can someone please show me an example of how to do this, or point me to some tutorial?

I should mention I am  new at working with databases.

Comment: There's not a lot to go on to answer your specific question. My recommendation is: forget about the specifics of your particular problem (i.e. inheritance/foreign keys) and simply step through any of the tutorials that come up on Google for "hibernate beginner tutorial". Once you have a run-of-the-mill object persisting to your database using your Java/Spring/Hibernate stack you'll be in much better shape to ask a more specific question and therefore get more specific answers. Good luck.

Comment: try actually looking on the hibernate website and trying to the find the answer there first.  If you don't show at least some effort on your part, most people will not offer you any help.

Comment: I have been at this for quiet a few days now. My first approach was to get rid of the inheritance and work with a single class. But that removed the whole Abstract-Syntax-Tree aspect of my classes, so it wasn't a suitable solution. And I have been going through documentations and tutorials.

I don't mean to sound cranky, but just want say that I have been putting effort into this.

Comment: You may have put tons of effort into it, but that doesn't show in the question.  You really should try to illustrate what you've tried already when asking the question, and where you've looked for answers.

Comment: All right, I'll do that the next I have a question. I had been looking at it as a MySQL problem, rather than Hybernate. My question was very general because I still had no idea in which direction to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.  i'm relatively sure the Table_Per_Class strategy will let you ask for any "Generic" object and query all it's subclass tables.  Keep in mind if you do this, the ID should be unique across all of your subclass types.  You'll have to figure out a strategy for this use the right annotations to tell hibernate what to do.  But in the mean time, this example assumes you're assigning it manually before saving.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Generic {
   @Id @Column(name="ID")
   private Long id;
   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="EXTA")
public class ExtA extends Generic {
   @Column(name="fieldA")
   private Generic fieldA;
}
```